# How to configure django-supervisord?

Tags: django-commands, django-supervisor

I'm trying to write a supervisord.conf for django fastcgi process in webfaction. When I run the command the supervisor immediately exited.

supervisord.conf

```
[program:celeryd]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celeryd -l info --settings=zone.webfaction
[program:celerycam]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celerycam --settings=zone.webfaction
[program:runserver]
exclude=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[program:celeryd]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celeryd -B -E -l info --settings=zone.webfaction
[program:celerycam]
command={{ PYTHON }} {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/manage.py celerycam --settings=zone.webfaction
[program:autoreload]
exclude=true
[program:runserver]
exclude=true
[program:celerybeat]
exclude=true
```